# How to write simple, but optimized left join for MySQL in Slick

Tags: mysql, scala, slick, slick-2.0

How would I write the equivalent of this LEFT OUTER JOIN query using Slick?

```
SELECT i.itemid, p.propvalue
FROM items i
LEFT JOIN properties p ON i.itemid = p.itemid AND p.propname = "Property Name"
WHERE i.available
```

I read the docs and it seemed like something like this was the way to go.

```
for {
  (i, p) <- Items leftJoin Properties on ((i, p) => (i.itemid === p.itemid && p.propname === "Property Name")) if i.available === 1.toByte
} yield (i.itemid, p.propvalue)
```

However, Slick writes a really complex query with subqueries which results in bad performance and actually causes MySQL to hang on what seems like any machine but my dev machine. I'm using Slick 2.02 on Scala 2.10.4.

I even get subqueries from something even simpler like this

```
for {
  (i, p) <- Items leftJoin Properties on (_.itemid === _.itemid)
} yield (i.itemid, p.propvalue)
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get Slick to write a LEFT JOIN like the one I've written in MySQL above?

Comment: Currently, I don't think there is a way other than writing SQL queries directly. You can get better discussion on https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/623

Comment: Thanks @mohit I'll follow that issue! Bummed just like everybody else that this doesn't work as expected with MySQL but glad I'm not doing something wrong.

Comment: Although #623 is closed, I'm not convinced this is fixed... https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scalaquery/J3pM5NBDW7U